# How to parallelize assertions to different dictionaries?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, pool

Given the following categories:

```py
categories = ['high', 'mid', 'low']
```

And I'm trying to parallelize the following function:

```py
def get_enriched_paths(dir_path, filenames, categories):

    goods = {c : [] for c in categories}
    bads = {c : [] for c in categories}

    for fn in filenames:
        for h in heights:
            if h not in os.listdir(dir_path):
                bads[h].append(fn)
            else:
                enriched_fn = enrich_filename(f'{dir_path}/{h}/fn')
                if enriched_fn is None:
                    bads[h].append(fn)
                else:
                    goods[h].append(enriched_fn)
    return goods, bads
```

I know that with `pool.map` I can create some list like:

```py
goods['low'] = pool.map(enrich_filename, [f'{path}/{h}/fn' for fn in filenames])
```

But with the conditions I can't figure it out..
There's an option to parallelize the function above using pool.map? Or anything else?

Comment: Why do you want to parallelise "the conditions"? You have two loops that you can parallelise – just like your ``pool.map`` example shown.

Answer (score 1):

On the assumption you are looking to parallel the problem at the

```
for fn in filenames:
```

stage...

I pretty much always use apply_async, might not be the fastest, not sure on that, but its definitely very flexible - see below:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def get_enriched_paths(path, filenames, categories):
    
    nCPUs = mp.cpu_count()
    pool = mp.Pool(nCPUs)
    fut = []  #Just a holding list for our SMP results

    goods = {c : [] for c in categories}
    bads = {c : [] for c in categories}

    for fn in filenames:
        #Send the job to worker
        fut.append(pool.apply_async(worker, args=(path, fn, heights)))  

    #Then recover the jobs from the pool
    for iFut in range(0, len(fut)):
        rtnGood, rtnBad = fut[iFut].get()

        #Not 100% sure on whether the dicts will extend nicely - might have to trial that a bit. worst case is you step through each key in rtnGood & rtnBad and append to the corresponding in goods & bads via: goods[key].extend(rtnGood[key]) 
        goods.extend(rtnGood)
        bads.extend(rtnBad)

    #and tidy up the SMP artefacts
    del fut
    pool.close()


    return goods, bads



def worker(path, fn, heights, ):
   #I'm sure worker could be coded far more elegant than this, its just a thrown together rough guess.
   tempBad = {}
   tempGood = {}
   for h in heights:
       tempBad[h] = []
       tempGood[h] = [] 

   for h in heights:
       if h not in os.listdir(path):
           tempBad[h].append(fn)
       else:
           enriched_fn = enrich_filename(f'{path}/{h}/fn')
           if parsed_data is None:  #Not quite sure where you get parsed_data from...?
               tempBad[h].append(fn)
           else:
               tempGood[h].append(enriched_fn)

    return tempGood, tempBad
```

I haven't tested the above, and may contain minor typos - but I've ran the same generic approach hundreds of times, so hopefully it'll work for you too.

Also note that python does take quite a while to spawn separate processes, so if you are expecting a return from each worker thread in well under a second, you'd be better served by chunking up the number of filenames into sublists. Or by making the job parallel at a different point.

Comment: Instead of a double-loop on ``apply_async`` and its futures, you can just [``map_async``](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map_async) (or outright ``map``).

Comment: Note that lists can be iterated directly – ``for future in fut:`` – without indexing, pool lifetime is best handled using ``with`` (which also works even in case of errors), and there is no need to ``del fut`` – they are freed at the end of the function anyway.

Comment: Do you know would it be any faster?  [I know it'd save a few lines of syntax]. edit: @ apply_async vs. map_async vs. map

Comment: ``map_async`` will internally do a loop, so it is mostly about moving complexity from your own code out into the library (which already maintains this complexity). If you care about these things, ``map_async`` will also take care of cleaning up any futures. However, any overhead of a single loop is negligible vs the overhead of ``multiprocessing`` sending the work to its backend processes.

Comment: I've found deleting the fut useful for keeping memory down. I've even had to del fut[iFut] - which is why I do tend to iterate over rather than iterate direct (which as you say, can indeed be done).

Comment: ... and the reason I almost exclusively use apply_async is a mix of laziness and flexibility - I can fire any kind of workload at it and it'll do it. The worker threads don't have to be common functions, nor do the arguments have to be the same shape or size. OK, needs a bit of care when recovering the data out - but since your in control of the sequence of workers within the pool at all times thats no big deal.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Can you elaborate about `map_async` ? how to use it properly in my code?

Comment: The processing pool maintains a queue of tasks to be performed and these tasks are grouped together in "chunks". So when a processor in the pool becomes idle it takes from the queue the next chunk of tasks to perform. Calling `apply_async` places a tasks on the queue one at a time in chunk sizes of 1. The `map` functions have a *chunksize* argument but if omitted defaults to approximately `ceil(iterable-size / 4 * pool-size)`, so there are fewer reads and writes to the queue. To compute this default *chunksize*, the length of the *iterable* argument must be known. (...more )

Comment: This cannot be the case with method `imap`, so the default *chunksize* argument is 1. But then the documentation for `imap` goes on to say that **For very long iterables using a large value for *chunksize* can make the job complete much faster than using the default value of `1`.** So I infer from that description it is better to reduce the number of queue accesses everything else being equal and that `map` might be more efficient than *lots* of calls to `apply_async`. Of course, if you need to create a list just to use `map` and it's now a very *large* list, that becomes a memory issue.

Comment: To use `map` you have to `from functools import partial`. Then instead of looping on `for fn in filenames:`, you make *fn* the last argument of function `worker` and then: `results = map(partial(worker, path, height), filenames)`. `results` will be a list of tuples that you can iterate, for example, `for rtnGood, rtnBad in results:`. The current code could be simplified with: `fut = [pool.apply_async(worker, args=(path, fn, heights)) for fn in filenames]` and `for f in fut: rtnGood, rtnBad = f.get()`.